# BeautifulSoup children() vs descendants()

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*I read a book that has the following:*

---

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html')

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for child in bs.find('table',{'id':'giftList'}).children: 

    print(child)
```

This code prints the list of product rows in the giftList table, including the initial row of column labels. If you were to write it using the descendants() function instead of the children() function, about two dozen tags would be found within the table and printed, including img tags, span tags, and individual td tags.

---

*I tested it and I did not see the two outputs had difference when using .children or .descendants. Can anyone please tell me what exactly it will print when using .children and using .descendants.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference lies in depth level. `children` will go to one level of depth max. `descendants` will print everything, going to the maximum depth every time.

if we take that excerpt from the `sisters.html` of the beautifulsoup docs

`<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>`

```
for child in p.children:
      print(child)
>>> <b>

for child in p.descendants:
      print(child)
>>> <b> 
>>> "The Dormouse's story"
```

Comment: I get it from the example you showed me. But what I don't get is the example from the book. My understanding was: using the .children, it should just print the <tr> tags only. But the result the code runs out is everything including the the tr, th, td, img and span tags. I assumed that kind of result (that has every tags) only happened when using .descendants. Am I correct?

Comment: i think you're confused by the output as each output spans multiple lines. instead of `print(child)` try `print(child.name)`: it will print only the name of one tag in one line. you'll see clearly the difference between both methods then

Comment: I got it now. I double checked the print out for both .children and .descendants and I can see the differences now. I just did not read the printout carefully enough at the first beginning. Thanks much!